# Update XML file tag text in QT c++

Tags: c++, xml, qt

```
<HmiRequest>
    <Type>AlertPopup</Type>
    <Id>123</Id>
    <Order>new</Order>
    <HmiContent>
        <ATBev_1000_Label_NatureOfCall>eCall</ATBev_1000_Label_NatureOfCall>
    </HmiContent>
</HmiRequest>
```

In the above xml file I wan to update Id value "123" with 111.
123 to 111.
I am able to update tag name but the value how can we change ?

Comment: show the code you already have

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
QDomDocument doc;
doc.setContent(QString("<HmiRequest>    <Type>AlertPopup</Type>    <Id>123</Id>    <Order>new</Order>    <HmiContent>        <ATBev_1000_Label_NatureOfCall>eCall</ATBev_1000_Label_NatureOfCall>    </HmiContent></HmiRequest>"), false);
QDomNodeList lstNodes = doc.documentElement().childNodes();
int iCount = lstNodes. count();
for (int i = 0; i < iCount; ++i)
{
    if (lstNodes.at(i).nodeName() == "Id")
    {
        QDomElement newIdTag = doc.createElement(QString("Id"));
        QDomText idVal = doc.createTextNode(QString("111"));
        newIdTag.appendChild(idVal);
        doc.documentElement().replaceChild(newIdTag, lstNodes.at(i));
        break;
    }
}
qDebug() << doc.toString(4);
```